# Field not updating with setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, apc

I have an entity class named 'education'

Part of its code shown below:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1024, nullable=true)
 */
private $locationn;

public function setLocationn($locationn)
{
    $this->locationn = $locationn;
}
public function getLocationn()
{
    return $this->locationn;
}
```

I have added field named `locationn` in it, but when I set proxy auto generate to `false` it stops updating the value but it works fine with proxy auto generate set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. `setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false)` is for production use and enables faster execution, because it does not check changes in source code files every time the app executes.

You should use CLI command `orm:generate-proxies` to regenerate proxy classes.

Comment: Yes I have regenerated the proxies even then it is not working. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: You should also clear your metadata cache. Use can use ArrayCache for development, but something like APC or Memcache storage for production.

Comment: Yes I am using APC cache for production and issue is on production only. When I work on development environment using array cache it works fine.

Comment: So you should clear it when you're deploying a new version. Then you will have fresh metadata loaded up.